# Tensorflow installation error: not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: installation, pip, python-wheel, tensorflow

when I try to install TensorFlow by cloning from Git, I run into the error "no module named copyreg," so I tried installing using a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). However, I then run into this error:

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl

tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I don't see this under the common problems section.

I am using [OS X v10.10.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite) and Python 3.4.3, but I also have Python 2.7 (I am unsure if pip differentiates between these or how to switch between them).

Comment: Which OS version and Python version do you have on your machine?

Comment: Using OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 and python 3.4.3, but I also have python 2.7 (unsure if pip differentiates between  these or how to switch between them)

Comment: Same problem here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/695981/platform-not-supported-for-tensorflow-on-ubuntu-14-04-2

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I too got the same problem.

I downloaded `get-pip.py` from *https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py* and then ran `python2.7 get-pip.py` for installing `pip2.7`.

And then ran the `pip install` command with `python2.7` as follows.

**For Ubuntu/Linux:**

```
python2.7 -m pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

**For Mac OS X:**

```
python2.7 -m pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

This should work just fine as it did for me :)

I followed these instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695981/platform-not-supported-for-tensorflow-on-ubuntu-14-04-2).

Comment: Thank you! Just changed the link to https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl and it works fine (for now)

Comment: you are welcome :)
and thank you for pointing out the link for mac OS
edited the answer

Comment: For those who use vmware under Windows, the `get-pip.py` file downloaded in Windows will get `not a supported wheel on this platform` error in Ubuntu as well.

Comment: This did not fix the problem for me using virtualbox instead of vmware

Comment: I'm facing same problem on my Windows PC too, what shall I do? I didn't get any sophisticated answer of it. Is there anyone here to help me.

Comment: The key for me was `python -m pip`. Running pip directly didn't work, but loading it as a module did.

Answer (score 25):

After activating the virtualenv, be sure to upgrade pip to the latest version.

```
(your_virtual_env)$  pip install --upgrade pip
```

And now you'll be able to install TensorFlow correctly (for Linux):

```
(your_virtual_env)$  pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.7.0-py2-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted. I recommend this one over the other one. +1.

Comment: No help here, and I'm on pip version 9.

Comment: This solved my problem. recommend trying this out before the selected answer

Answer (score 12):

I was trying to do the Windows-based install and kept getting this error.

It turns out you **have to** have Python 3.5.2. Not 2.7, not 3.6.x-- nothing other than 3.5.2.

After installing Python 3.5.2, the `pip install` worked.

Comment: Hi, 
I encountered the same problem. I followed your instructions but it seems that it didn't help... It still writes "tensorflow... is not a supported wheel on this platform"

Comment: Yea, I bypassed the error that read `tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`. The installation went through though. Thnx

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that the wheel is, well, supported by your platform. Pip uses the wheel's filename to determine compatibility. The format is:

```
tensorflow-{version}-{python version}-none-{your platform}.whl
```

I didn't realize that `x86_64` refers to x64, I thought it meant *either* x86 or x64, so I banged my head against this futilely for some time. TensorFlow is not available for 32-bit systems, unless you want to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that TensorFlow only works on Python 3.5 at the moment. Try to run this command before running the **pip install**

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
```

After this, run the following lines:

For **CPU**:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

For **GPU**:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

It should work like a charm.

Comment: You forgot to execute `activate tensorflow`, right?

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 10, with Python 3.6.X version I was facing the same. Then after checking deliberately, I noticed I had Python-32 bit installation on my 64-bit machine. Remember TensorFlow is only compatible with a 64-bit installation of Python. **Not 32 bit of Python**

[image: Installation requirements]

If we download Python from python.org, the default installation would be 32 bit. So we have to download the 64 bit installer manually to install Python 64 bit. And then add

1. C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
2. C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts

Then run `gpupdate /Force` on the command prompt. If the Python command doesn’t work for 64 bit, restart your machine.

Then run the Python interpreter on the command prompt. It should show 64 bit

```
python

Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Then run the below command to install the TensorFlow CPU version (recommended)

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Answer (score 3):

The pip wheel file contains the Python version in its name (cp34-cp34m). If you download the .whl file and rename it to say **py3-none** or instead, it should work. Can you try that?

The installation won't work for [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) users that choose Python 3 support, because the installation procedure is asking to create a Python 3.5 environment and the file is currently called *cp34-cp34m*. So renaming it would do the job for now.

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.7.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

This will produce the exact error message you got above. However, when you will download the file yourself and rename it to "tensorflow-0.7.0-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl", then execute the command again with the changed filename, it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10 64 bit:

I have tried all the suggestions here, but finally I got it running as follows:

1. Uninstall all current versions of Python
2. Remove all Python references in the PATH system and user environment variables
3. Download the latest 64-bit version of Python 3.8: Python 3.8.7 currently, *not* the latest 3.9.x version which is the one I was using, and *not* 32 bit.
4. Install with all options selected, including pip, and including the PATH environment variable
5. `pip install tensorflow` (in an administrator CMD prompt)
6. Upgrade pip if prompted (optional)

Comment: This worked for me with Python 3.8.10.
pip downloaded the following: tensorflow-2.6.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
Looks like this may have worked for 3.9 now, as I see a URL for 3.9 support in the tensorflow install instructions.
I was initially trying with python 3.10

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use Python 3.5.*.

I successfully solved this problem with Python 3.5.3. Modify the Python version to 3.5.* in [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)). See *[Managing Python](https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html)*.

Then go to https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows, and repeat from "Create a Conda environment named *tensorflow* by invoking the following command" bla, bla...

Comment: The second link is broken (*"404. Sorry, we couldn't find that page."*).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install from source and got that error. (Why would a wheel built on this machine not be compatible with it?)

For me, the tag `--ignore-installed` made all the difference.

```
pip install --ignore-installed /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

worked, while

```
pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

threw the abovementioned error.

Context: [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) environment; it might have been a problem specific to this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are installing the wrong pre-build binary?

Check on https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build

For my [Coffee Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_Lake) processor on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) the download URL was:

https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build/releases/download/tf1.12.0-ubuntu18.04-py2-py3/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade <PATH>
```

resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and tried all the solutions that folks suggested here and other links (like *[Platform not supported for TensorFlow on Ubuntu 14.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695981/platform-not-supported-for-tensorflow-on-ubuntu-14-04-2)*).

It was so frustrating because using `print(wheel.pep425tags.get_supported())` I could see that my [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) supported ('cp37', 'cp37m', 'linux_x86_64') and that was exactly what I was trying to install (from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl).

What at the end fixed it was to simply download the package first and then

```
pip install tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install CPU TensorFlow on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver), and the best way (for me...) I found for it was using it on top of Conda, for that:

1. To create a Conda ‘tensorflow’ environment. Follow *[How to Install Anaconda on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04/)*
2. After all is installed, see *[Getting started with conda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html)*. And use it according to *[Managing environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#managing-environments)*
3. `conda create --name tensorflow`
4. `source  activate tenso`rflow
5. `pip install --upgrade pip`
6. `pip uninstall tensorflow`
7. For CPU: `pip install tensorflow-cpu`, for GPU: `pip install tensorflow`
8. `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow`
9. Test TF E.g. on 'Where' with:

> python

```
import tensorflow as tf

>>> tf.where([[True, False], [False, True]])
```

Expected result:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1]])>
```

- After the Conda upgrade, I got:

  ```
  DeprecationWarning: 'source deactivate' is deprecated. Use 'conda deactivate'.
  ```

So you should use:

```
‘conda activate tensorflow’ / ‘conda deactivate’
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the version of your default Python interpreter (`python -V`) and the version of your default pip (`pip -V`) do not match. You have built TensorFlow with your default Python interpreter and trying to use a different pip version to install it.

In Mac, delete */usr/local/bin/pip* and rename (copy) *pipx.y* (whatever x.y version that matches your Python version) to pip in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

system requirement Python 3.7–3.10

macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (no GPU support)

```
pip install tensorflow-macos
```