# Getting: tensorflow is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: tensorflow

I tried installing tensorflow on my system, but I received the following error:

tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

**Exception Information captured in pip.log file:-**

---

/home/gansai/tensorflow/bin/pip run on Wed Nov 11 00:19:05 2015

tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/gansai/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

File "/home/gansai/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 269, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))

File "/home/gansai/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 168, in from_line
    raise UnsupportedWheel("%s is not a supported wheel on this platform." % wheel.filename)

UnsupportedWheel: tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

---

What could I do to install tensorflow and start experimenting it?

Comment: The whl files are specific to a set of hardware and software What are you using? Intel processor? 32-bit or 64-bit processor? OS? etc.

Comment: Intel Core 2 Duo, Debian OS - i686 (arch)

Comment: I have installed TensorFlow three different ways: 1 from binary on VMWare running Debian, 2 from source on VMWare running Debian, 3 from Docker on Windows. I was able to get each one to install. I did have some problems but by carefully reading the instructions I achieved success. I don't know what more to ask. Try doing a source build instead of binary install.

Comment: I was using a 32 bit, but to start using TensorFlow, I installed a 64 bit debian and tried the steps mentioned by @Sasidhar below, but that also returned few errors, finally I tried docker based installation, which worked fine and started doing some examples, will post answer below. Thanks.

Comment: I did a Docker install but ran out of memory. Since I had TensorFlow working from the source I stuck with that. I would ask that you try a few examples before posting your answer, you may run into issues you don't forsee. Glad you have it working.

Comment: Hi @GuyCoder, thanks.. I tried installing with pip again, found that I had to install python-dev package too. After that, thanks to all, I could install tensorflow and could try the examples well. So, shall I update answer with these details?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform*

The above error comes because of trying to install TensorFlow onto a 32 bit system. As you could observe, the wheel was linux_x86_64, which is intended to be installed on 64 bit.

Steps to follow:-

Direct Binary Installation

1. Install Debian 64 bit OS. Download debian 64 bit ISO from torrent (http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/bt-hybrid/)
2. Install python-dev. `apt-get install python-dev`
3. Install tensor-flow `python2.7 -m pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

Docker Based Installation

1. Install Debian 64 bit OS. Download debian 64 bit ISO from torrent (http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/bt-hybrid/)
2. Install Docker on Debian. Follow steps mentioned in http://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/debian/#debian-jessie-80-64-bit
3. Run docker container for tensorflow. `docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow`. Follow steps mentioned in http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#docker-based_installation

The main point to be noted here is that, as of now, python wheel for tensorflow is supported for 64 bit system, as shared in `pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

Answer (score 10):

I guess pip3 is being used for installation
it can be solved by using pip2.7

I followed the steps in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33635645/3057648)

hope it helps you:)

Comment: Hi Sasidhar, I followed the steps, but did not work. :(

Comment: Hi Sasidhar, My debian was 32 bit, so I had installed 64 bit debian and installed python-dev package and could atlast install tensorflow and try some examples. :)

Answer (score 1):

It might be unrelated but I had the same error with tensorflow-0.7.1-cp34-none-linux_x86_64.whl on a fresh Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS (64bit) and this is what has helped:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools -y && sudo easy_install3 pip -y && sudo apt-get install python 3.5-dev -y && sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev -y
sudo pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp34-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

You can call a tensorflow script like this:

```
#call it with python3.4
python3.4 tensorflow_demo.py
```

While researching I often read about using wget and renaming the file but this became obsolete with the latest version, see here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1142#issuecomment-186740120