# Tensorflow Wheel Install not Supported

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

In Anaconda3, Im trying to install the wheel but it is not working. On Windows. Using Python 3.6. There isnt a 3.6 wheel. I get this error:

```
tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: This may be helpful :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622613/tensorflow-installation-error-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

I have Python 3.5.2 installed. Using the installation method given by Tensorflow, shows downloading Anaconda, which automatically installs Python 3.6

Comment: Please file an issue on our github issue page, referencing this thread. We might want to update the documentation.

Comment: Is the version 0.12 mandatory? Because if you can use the latest release, you can install it with `pip install tensorflow` and it should work

Comment: drpng - whats the url?

nessuno - Im stuck on Step 4 (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows), after activating tensorflow

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl

Comment: The URL for creating an issue is https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new

Answer (score 3):

Use an alternative tensorflow wheel for Python 3.6:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.0rc2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** TensorFlow from version 1.2 forward officially supports Python 3.6

There is no wheel for Python 3.6 for currently not being supported on Windows yet.
As you can see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6999), Python 3.6 support on Windows is a work in progress. 
The only alternative to use TensorFlow on Windows with Python 3.6 is to build it from source.

Comment: Then why did Tensorflow require me to download Python 3.6? How do I force 3.5 to stay?

Comment: TensorFlow does not require you install Python 3.6 for Windows. If you opted to use the Anaconda distribution what happens is Anaconda updated their Python 3.5 distribution to 3.6, so your alternative to use Anaconda with TensorFlow on Windows is build from source or create a conda environment for Python 3.5 as follows:
`conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5`

`activate tensorflow`
`pip install tensorflow`. 
As you can see on [this open issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6999) support for Python 3.6 on Windows is a current work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem.
Before they update TensorFlow.
You can try to download the historical version of his 2016-9-27 on [this website](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just change your python version to 3.5 and then retry installing tensorflow. Tensorflow is only compatible with Python 3.5

```
conda install python=3.5
```

and then

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```