# how to install tensorflow ? tensorflow-1.1.0-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: tensorflow

C:\Users\Sudhit> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/…

tensorflow-1.1.0-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

How will I know which will be supported wheel for my platform?

Comment: What platform are you running? Which version of Windows? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: I am using 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

This question already asked by someone here [Tensorflow installation error: not a supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622613/tensorflow-installation-error-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

If you are using conda use below command to install tensorflow.

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
conda install jupyter
conda install scipy
pip install tensorflow
\# or
\# pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

or

On Linux

```
python2.7 -m pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is only compatible for 64 bit version of Python. So, make sure it is by :

```
>python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Then, simply, upgrade pip using:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Lastly, install tensorflow:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Done!

You can verify the install using:

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```