# How to activate a specific Anaconda environment from PHP

Tags: php, python, anaconda

I'm using PHP to run python scripts using the `exec()` function.

After installing [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/) and making it the default Python install by placing it first in my`PATH` variable, I was able to import all the modules I needed like [Scikit Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/), [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) etc, and still run the script from PHP using `exec()`.

Here's the problem: when I installed [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org) (with Anaconda), by following the instruction on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) page, it needs you to activate the Anaconda environment after the install before you can actually use it. It works when I do it on the command line, but I how can I reproduce that activation process from a PHP script? I, understandably get the `ModuleNotFoundError`. Or to rephrase, how can I make importing Tensorflow as effortless as the other modules that come with Anaconda? Am I missing something?

Comment: just to clarify, you have installed tensorflow in the environment and NOT in the root of anaconda? It should have nothing to do with the module and by the sounds of it you are getting confused between the built in packages in the root of anaconda and what's installed in an environment. Can you please clarify exactly how you're configured everything?

Comment: I created a conda environment using:
'conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5' and then activated it using: 'activate tensorflow' and then used 'pip install' from within the environment. Is there another way? Can I install it in the root?

Comment: No that sounds right. It sounds like you're not activating your anaconda directory when you make your php calls. I've not done any work in this though so dont want to lead you down the wrong path. There are probably tutorials available on how to use environments within php somewhere

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions, any way of running tensorflow in python from a PHP call?

Comment: Again, i've never used python through php so I have no idea. Does activating the environment through a shell call before running a file work? I'm not sure sorry. Hopefully someone else can come and give you more help.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, unfortunately no. Thanks any way :)

Comment: Why not just install `tensorflow` into the root (default) environment?

Comment: Without using Anaconda @darthbith?

Comment: No, into the root environment of Anaconda. In other words, why create an Anaconda environment just for tensorflow? You said all the other packages worked, why not just install tensorflow there?

Comment: Oh god, yeah, it works now. I did try doing that before, but it didn't work because I was using a different python version, and apparently Tensorflow only works with 3.5.2 . More information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622613/tensorflow-installation-error-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by installing Tensorflow in the root, rather than an environment. Keep in mind though, if you're on Windows like me, you'll need to have Python 3.5.2. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622613/tensorflow-installation-error-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)