# I keep having issues when installing pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I've used pandas before, but not for a while. 
I had it for Python 2 and recently upgraded to Python 3, so I'm not sure if that is the underlying issue.

When I do pip install pandas, I get this error message:

```
Installing collected packages: numpy, pandas
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/f1/v91lpd7j2ls5tbs3qlbr0q5c0000gn/T/pip-DTCBbT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: Are you trying to install to your Python 3 interpreter? Have you considered using something like Anaconda?

Comment: what python version are you trying to install this for? and do you already have these libraries installed on another verison?

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo pip install pandas`?

Comment: Hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me can correct me: if Python 2.7 is the default system Python, `pip install` tries to install to Python2, correct? As such, would running `pip3 install` install to Python 3? I think I originally came across that tidbit here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40036679/6672746

Comment: The pip3 install worked!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sudo` command to install the module:

`[usr@osx ~] sudo pip install pandas`

EDIT:

Based on the information in your question

`[usr@osx ~] sudo pip install pandas`

will install `pandas` to your Python 2.7 interpreter, if you want it installed for your Python 3 interpreter then you will need to run the following:

`[usr@osx ~] sudo python3 -m pip install pandas`

Comment: I tried sudo and it did not work; I got the same error. However, I just tried the pip3 install and it worked!

Comment: Good to know. Im glad you got it working. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: Hmmm it might help someone else!