# Tensorflow package not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I am not that well-versed in the packages installation but my Anaconda software has been working perfectly. I tried to install the packages via [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-keras-tensorflow-using-anaconda-for-machine-learning-44ab28ff39cb) for running Keras and Tensorflow. However, I face the same error whenever I try to install Tensorflow CPU version using the Anaconda Prompt or Command prompt.

I don't know how to deal with this. I've used

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

The `.whl` files are throwing errors that it doesn't support the platform. 
How else should I install Tensorflow?

PS. I also added conda-forge to my channels list. Still the same error:
[image: Console showing error text]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow installation error: not a supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622613/tensorflow-installation-error-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

Comment: Try this 
1. Upgrade pippip install --upgrade pip
2. pip install tensorflow

Comment: I tried to upgrade pip and then install tensorflow.. My pip is already up-to-date and it didn't work. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `conda` is looking in `win32` channels. You therefore seem to have installed anaconda as 32-bit. For 32-bit, tensorflow is not available, as you can see in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install):

> TensorFlow is tested and supported on the following 64-bit systems

Also see [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20362)

If you have 32-bit windows then you need to upgrade to a 64-bit system to use tensorflow

If you have a 64-bit system but just downloaded the wrong anaconda version, go ahead and remove it and reinstall using the 64-bit installer

Comment: Yeah thanks.. I just browsed through the other questions and noticed that.. Thanks :) I got 64 bit and its working