# Cannot install tensorflow using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to call a simple `keras.Sequential()` model in python 3.9 (64bit), however when trying to install `tensorflow` using `pip` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Having stacked this error I followed this fix: [TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip) and tried to use the latest version of CPU only windows wheel using the following command:

```
install python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

However I then get the following error:

```
ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

The only answer on this that I can find is this:
[Tensorflow installation error: not a supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622613/tensorflow-installation-error-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

However the answer relates to `python2.7` and does not apply to this situation.

Is anyone able to help understand why I am finding it so difficult to install `tensorflow`.

Thanks.

Comment: Please downgrade your python version like 3.8 or below

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [TensorFlow only supports Python 3.5-3.8](https://www.tensorflow.org/install), so you are unable to install it because your version of Python is 3.9.

You will need to use a different version of Python if you want to install TensorFlow.