# Application Error after successfully deploying Django API to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am making an api for my deep learning model. The api is properly working on localhost. I tried to deploy it on Heroku. It is deployed but when I open the link it gives "Application error" like below image

[image: Application error image]

**Release log:**

```
2021-02-23 05:47:36.841582: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

**Build log:**

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Python app detected
 !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.7.10
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
-----> Installing python-3.7.8
-----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting absl-py==0.11.0
         Downloading absl_py-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
       Collecting asgiref==3.3.1
         Downloading asgiref-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Collecting astunparse==1.6.3
         Downloading astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
       Collecting cachetools==4.2.1
         Downloading cachetools-4.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
       Collecting certifi==2020.12.5
         Downloading certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
       Collecting chardet==4.0.0
         Downloading chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
       Collecting dj-database-url==0.5.0
         Downloading dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
       Collecting Django==3.1.7
         Downloading Django-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
       Collecting djangorestframework==3.12.2
         Downloading djangorestframework-3.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (957 kB)
       Collecting flatbuffers==1.12
         Downloading flatbuffers-1.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
       Collecting gast==0.3.3
         Downloading gast-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.7 kB)
       Collecting google-auth==1.27.0
         Downloading google_auth-1.27.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (135 kB)
       Collecting google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.2
         Downloading google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
       Collecting google-pasta==0.2.0
         Downloading google_pasta-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
       Collecting grpcio==1.32.0
         Downloading grpcio-1.32.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.8 MB)
       Collecting gunicorn==20.0.4
         Downloading gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
       Collecting h5py==2.10.0
         Downloading h5py-2.10.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.9 MB)
       Collecting idna==2.10
         Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
       Collecting Keras==2.4.3
         Downloading Keras-2.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
       Collecting Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
         Downloading Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
       Collecting Markdown==3.3.3
         Downloading Markdown-3.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
       Collecting numpy==1.19.5
         Downloading numpy-1.19.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.8 MB)
       Collecting oauthlib==3.1.0
         Downloading oauthlib-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
       Collecting opencv-python-headless==4.5.1.48
         Downloading opencv_python_headless-4.5.1.48-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (37.6 MB)
       Collecting opt-einsum==3.3.0
         Downloading opt_einsum-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
       Collecting Pillow==8.1.0
         Downloading Pillow-8.1.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
       Collecting protobuf==3.15.1
         Downloading protobuf-3.15.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
       Collecting psycopg2==2.8.6
         Downloading psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
       Collecting pyasn1==0.4.8
         Downloading pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
       Collecting pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
         Downloading pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
       Collecting pytz==2021.1
         Downloading pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
       Collecting PyYAML==5.4.1
         Downloading PyYAML-5.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (636 kB)
       Collecting requests==2.25.1
         Downloading requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
       Collecting requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
         Downloading requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
       Collecting rsa==4.7.1
         Downloading rsa-4.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
       Collecting scipy==1.6.1
         Downloading scipy-1.6.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (27.4 MB)
       Collecting six==1.15.0
         Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
       Collecting sqlparse==0.4.1
         Downloading sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
       Collecting tensorboard==2.4.1
         Downloading tensorboard-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (10.6 MB)
       Collecting tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
         Downloading tensorboard_plugin_wit-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (781 kB)
       Collecting tensorflow-cpu==2.4.1
         Downloading tensorflow_cpu-2.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (144.1 MB)
       Collecting tensorflow-estimator==2.4.0
         Downloading tensorflow_estimator-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (462 kB)
       Collecting termcolor==1.1.0
         Downloading termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz (3.9 kB)
       Collecting typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
         Downloading typing_extensions-3.7.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
       Collecting urllib3==1.26.3
         Downloading urllib3-1.26.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (137 kB)
       Collecting Werkzeug==1.0.1
         Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
       Collecting whitenoise==5.2.0
         Downloading whitenoise-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Collecting wrapt==1.12.1
         Downloading wrapt-1.12.1.tar.gz (27 kB)
       Collecting importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"
         Downloading importlib_metadata-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
       Collecting zipp>=0.5
         Downloading zipp-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.2 kB)
       Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2, termcolor, wrapt
         Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for psycopg2: filename=psycopg2-2.8.6-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl size=501629 sha256=d8931f1a9c43a4fda009cc1dd73998b6850c5cc8cd0b7262297232221c4cf24d
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-f0cb0bho/wheels/25/78/75/9c0323f7e1fb42143cbd2439302beb7850a1034abb961cb281
         Building wheel for termcolor (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for termcolor (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for termcolor: filename=termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl size=4830 sha256=ba9857e440ee6b55aede8e87e2b021b3a0083e509349a35a86d794ec3e6a7d15
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-f0cb0bho/wheels/3f/e3/ec/8a8336ff196023622fbcb36de0c5a5c218cbb24111d1d4c7f2
         Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for wrapt: filename=wrapt-1.12.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl size=77160 sha256=d9035ca277353f42fff12ec8f3a38fea5ee667bac754005cdd9b12f528fd3847
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-f0cb0bho/wheels/62/76/4c/aa25851149f3f6d9785f6c869387ad82b3fd37582fa8147ac6
       Successfully built psycopg2 termcolor wrapt
       ERROR: tensorflow-cpu 2.4.1 has requirement wheel~=0.35, but you'll have wheel 0.34.2 which is incompatible.
       Installing collected packages: six, absl-py, asgiref, astunparse, cachetools, certifi, chardet, dj-database-url, pytz, sqlparse, Django, djangorestframework, flatbuffers, gast, pyasn1, rsa, pyasn1-modules, google-auth, oauthlib, urllib3, idna, requests, requests-oauthlib, google-auth-oauthlib, google-pasta, grpcio, gunicorn, numpy, h5py, scipy, PyYAML, Keras, Keras-Preprocessing, typing-extensions, zipp, importlib-metadata, Markdown, opencv-python-headless, opt-einsum, Pillow, protobuf, psycopg2, Werkzeug, tensorboard-plugin-wit, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, wrapt, termcolor, tensorflow-cpu, whitenoise
       Successfully installed Django-3.1.7 Keras-2.4.3 Keras-Preprocessing-1.1.2 Markdown-3.3.3 Pillow-8.1.0 PyYAML-5.4.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 absl-py-0.11.0 asgiref-3.3.1 astunparse-1.6.3 cachetools-4.2.1 certifi-2020.12.5 chardet-4.0.0 dj-database-url-0.5.0 djangorestframework-3.12.2 flatbuffers-1.12 gast-0.3.3 google-auth-1.27.0 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.2 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.32.0 gunicorn-20.0.4 h5py-2.10.0 idna-2.10 importlib-metadata-3.4.0 numpy-1.19.5 oauthlib-3.1.0 opencv-python-headless-4.5.1.48 opt-einsum-3.3.0 protobuf-3.15.1 psycopg2-2.8.6 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pytz-2021.1 requests-2.25.1 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 rsa-4.7.1 scipy-1.6.1 six-1.15.0 sqlparse-0.4.1 tensorboard-2.4.1 tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.8.0 tensorflow-cpu-2.4.1 tensorflow-estimator-2.4.0 termcolor-1.1.0 typing-extensions-3.7.4.3 urllib3-1.26.3 whitenoise-5.2.0 wrapt-1.12.1 zipp-3.4.0
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> release, web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 305.3M
-----> Launching...
 !     Warning: Your slug size (305 MB) exceeds our soft limit (300 MB) which may affect boot time.
       Released v17
       https://damp-bayou-18222.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

**Output of `heroku logs --dyno router`**

```
2021-02-23T06:06:58.983807+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=damp-bayou-18222.herokuapp.com request_id=9d41bcd3-8555-4a03-a247-43ff200d5061 fwd="27.61.161.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-02-23T06:06:59.611890+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=damp-bayou-18222.herokuapp.com request_id=c4a3e114-c3af-4230-8081-63dd4401f113 fwd="27.61.161.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol
```

**Procfile**

```
release: python manage.py makemigrations --no-input
release: python manage.py migrate --no-input

web: gunicorn digitrec.wsgi
```

When I run the command **heroku ps:sacle web=1** it gives the below output:

`Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free`

I have tried many solutions from different answers of stackoverflow but nothing worked. Please help me out!!!

Comment: Hello, @ Yash Paneliya check this post i think it will useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622613/tensorflow-installation-error-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform

Answer (score 1):

Add `log-file` flag in web worker config

```
web: gunicorn digitrec.wsgi --log-file -
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning: Your slug size (305 MB) exceeds our soft limit (300 MB) which may affect boot time.
```

Your app must boot within the time limit or it'll be killed

Using the `release` phase in the `Procfile` works, but the release phase isn't part of the build, meaning that the `makemigrations` command creates the files in an ephemeral file system, meaning your next push will create brand new migrations again, which can cause issues with the database.

Finally, if your app is serving any sort of static files, and is used in production, then the `DEBUG` setting being `False` will mean you'll have to run `collectstatic` (again, as part of the build and not release).