# ERROR: tensorflow-2.8.0-cp39-none-linux_aarch64.whl

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to install `$ pip install tensorflow-2.8.0-cp39-none-linux_aarch64.whl` **tensorflow** on my **Raspberry Pi4** but I kept getting this error. Does anyone know how I can resolve it? My Pi architecture is **aarch64**, and my python version in the Pi terminal is 3.9.2.

`ERROR: tensorflow-2.8.0-cp39-none-linux_aarch64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`

Comment: What error? You did not include any error message.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy, I'm sorry for the oversight. That's the error that keep popping up

Comment: Is it the correct wheel for your platform? The error message seems to indicate that `aarch64` is not fit for your Raspberry Pi4. Also, is your Python version on that raspberry 3.9?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "filename.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/error-filename-whl-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform) Especially the comments in the accepted answer can be useful

Comment: Are you running Debian ARM64. The website says that this is a requirement.

Comment: @DARSIN, yea that's the Pi's OS (aarch64) - Bullseye

Comment: You can try something think this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622613/tensorflow-installation-error-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform